# ASP.NET MVC Lowercase URL doesn't work after Publishing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, seo, canonicalization

i have a ASP.NET MVC5 Site running successfully at www.hoxat.com. for SEO purposes , i have used Canonicalize Nuget Package and used following code

```
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
        routes.AppendTrailingSlash = false;
        routes.Canonicalize().Www().Lowercase().NoTrailingSlash();
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

During Debug / Release , the code works fine and all URL's are converted to lower case and slash is removed but after Publishing and uploading , these doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I Think the problem in **IIS** and `web.config`..